# Quantile for CompoundPoissonDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I need Quantile for CompoundPoissonDistribution, for example

```
Quantile[CompoundPoissonDistribution[1, GammaDistribution[100, 200]], 0.95]
```

I have Mathematica 9. Any idea how to get it?

Thx for answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thx for reaction. No, it is not critical.

Answer (score 6):

You could find it via simulation:

```
In[187]:= 
sample = RandomVariate[
   CompoundPoissonDistribution[1, GammaDistribution[100, 200]], 10^7];

In[188]:= Quantile[sample, 0.95`]

Out[188]= 59877.1
```

Comment: Thx for answer. And is there any way hot to calculate exact quantiles of Poisson-Gamma distribution using Mathematic?

Answer (score 6):

You can approximate the `Quantile` using data generated with `RandomVariate`

```
dist = CompoundPoissonDistribution[1, GammaDistribution[100, 200]];
```

While you can calculate the `Mean` and `StandardDeviation`, `PDF` or `CDF` and by extension `Quantile` don't evaluate with this `CompoundPoissonDistribution`

```
{μ, σ} = {Mean[dist], StandardDeviation[dist] // N}

(*  {20000, 20099.8}  *)
```

`PDF` and `CDF` return unevaluated

```
{PDF[dist, 20000.], CDF[dist, 20000.]}

(*  {PDF[CompoundPoissonDistribution[1, GammaDistribution[100, 200]], 20000.], 
 CDF[CompoundPoissonDistribution[1, GammaDistribution[100, 200]], 20000.]}  *)
```

Approximating

```
SeedRandom[1];

data = RandomVariate[dist, 10000];

{μest, σest} = {Mean[data], StandardDeviation[data]}

(*  {19998.9, 19910.6}  *)
```

Comparing with the theoretical values

```
({μest, σest} - {μ, σ})/{μ, σ}

(*  {-0.0000548537, -0.00940959}  *)
```

The approximate `Quantile` is

```
q95est = Quantile[data, 0.95]

(*  59850.  *)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. And is there any way hot to calculate exact quantiles of Poisson-Gamma distribution using Mathematic? Why I can not use Quantile[] on CompoundPoissonDistribution[], if I am able to use Mean[], Variance[] and other things...

Comment: @JonasVojtech - `PDF`, `CDF`, and `Quantile` are more complicated calculations than `Mean` or StandardDeviation` and Mathematica doesn't have the rules/transformations/algorithms built in to evaluate the more complicated  calculations--assuming that they can even be done in closed form.

Answer (score 6):

The OP seeks a symbolic/theoretical solution. To proceed symbolically, consider first what the OP is actually asking. The question is this:

**The Question**

Let  $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$, and let $\{X_1, X_2,\dots, X_m\}$ denote an iid sample of size $m$, where the sample size $m$ (instead of being fixed) is itself a Poisson random variable $M=m$. The OP seeks the distribution of the sample sum:

$$Y = X_1 + X_2 +  \dots + X_m \quad \quad \text{where} \quad M \sim \text{Poisson}(1)$$

As $M$ is Poisson, and the domain of support of a Poisson includes 0, it follows that the sample size $M$ can be 0, in which case $Y = 0$. This is important, because it means that $P(Y = 0)$ will have discrete mass.

The OP has sought to implement this model by using the syntax:

```
    CompoundPoissonDistribution[1, GammaDistribution[a, b]]
```

but unfortunately it does not seem to work with `PDF` or `CDF` etc

**Solution**

To proceed, first note that the sum of $m$ independent identical $\text{Gamma}(a,b)$ variables has a $\text{Gamma}(m a,b)$ distribution *i.e.* $Y$ has pdf $f(y \; \big| \; M = m)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/GammaYsumpdf.png))</sub>

where parameter $M \sim \text{Poisson}(1)$ with pmf $g(m)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/standardPoissonpmf.png))</sub>

We seek the parameter mixture distribution of $Y$ and $M$, which in standard *Mathematica* syntax, is:

```
PDF[ParameterMixtureDistribution[GammaDistribution[m a, b], 
  m \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[1]], y]
```

Unfortunately, this too does not work, irrespective of whether one enters numbers for the parameters $a$ and $b$, or symbols, or even numerical values for $y$ -- Mma just whirrs or returns `Undefined`. So, let us try a different approach ...

**Unconditional pdf of $Y$**

- Discrete Part:  $Y = 0$

$Y = 0$ iff $m = 0$. This occurs with probability $P(M=0)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/poisson0mass.png))</sub>

- Continuous Part: 
  The parameter-mix distribution, for $Y>0$, is given by:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/parametermixGammaPoissonpart2.png))</sub>

where:

- I am using the `Expect` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*
- The OP has specified some numerical values for $a$ and $b$ (e.g. $a = 100$ and $b = 200$). Mma can find a solution as a function of arbitrary $b$, so long as a numerical value for $a$ is set. Here, without loss of generality, we have set $a = 1$. It works just as well with $a=100$ ... the answer will just take longer to produce, and be more messy.

In summary, the unconditional pdf of $Y$ is:

$$\text{pdf}(Y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{e} & \text{ if } y = 0 \\
\text{sol} & \text{ if } y > 0 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

which is a mixed discrete-continuous distribution.

**Quantiles**

*Mathematica* cannot integrate the `Hypergeometric0F1Regularized` above, but we can still make our own numerical probability or cdf function (here, with say $b =10$):

```
NProb[w_?NumericQ] := 1/E + NIntegrate[sol /. b -> 10, {y, 0, w}]
```

For example, when $a = 1$ and $b=10$, the $P(Y\leq 20)$ is:

```
NProb[20]
```

> 0.817415

Then, the 0.95 quantile is found with:

```
FindRoot[NProb[y] == 0.95, {y, 10, 100}]
```

> {y -> 39.1804}

In the OP's case, with $a = 100$ and $b=200$, the same approach yields:

```
FindRoot[NProb[y] == 0.95, {y, 20000, 100000}]
```

> {y -> 59883.1}

Verify that it is correct:

```
NProb[59883.1]
```

> 0.95

And all is good.

**Checking and Testing Simulation Answers posted by others**
Just for fun, the two simulation answers produced (see other answers) return:

```
NProb[59850]
```

> 0.949766

```
NProb[59877.1]
```

> 0.949958

Comment: Thx for your answer. Is there any way how to get  the mathStatica package for free or how to replace the function Expect? Thank you.

Comment: @JonasVojtech If you don't have a copy of mathStatica, please email me, and I'd be happy to send you a copy.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry but I can not find your email. Could you send me your email here or info about the copy to jonas.vojtech@seznam.cz . Thank you! I tried to replace function Expect[], I used Expectation[f, m-PoissonDistribution[1]], but it is really time consuming. I hope correct.